# Apache Kafka is giving error "Unable to canonicalize address"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am starting Kafka in cluster mode with 3 Zookeeper instances and 3 Kafka brokers on 3 different unix hosts. I first started all the 3 Zookeeper instances, then I started running Kafka brokers. 2 brokers started fine, but the third broker is giving the following error:

```
[2021-06-02 18:51:59,101] WARN Session 0x0 for server 10.32.141.8/<unresolved>:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to canonicalize address 10.32.141.8/<unresolved>:2181 because it's not resolvable
        at org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:65)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:41)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1001)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1060)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by [ZOOKEEPER-3779](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3779) a result of [java bug 8232369](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8232369) introduced in java 14.

Upstep your zookeeper version or kafka version to fix this.

Comment: I confirm. Kafka 2.11-2.3.0 + Java 8: ok. Kafka 2.11-2.3.0 + Java 17: nok ("unable to canonicalize..."). Kafka 2.13-3.5.1 + Java 17: ok.

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/resolv.conf is resolver configuration file for Linux and UNIX like operating systems. It is used to configure dns name servers, compare the definitions between the working and not working servers

Answer (score -1):

remove all cached log files or change the directory of the log path of the server.properties file that you are going to run. the cache log files' data can be affected due to your server history.

if you are running the same localhost or same instance, your log file must be in separate locations. change every `log.dirs`s of the server.properties file's which you run.

```
#broker1
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
```

```
#broker2
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-2
```

```
#broker3
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-3
```